# concatenating array elements between first and last dynamically in php

Tags: php

i have searched on the Internet but i couldn't find a solution,  i have got a string which contain names(two, three,..) of a staff.
i want to extract from this string the `first name, middle names and last name`

sample string

```
$name = "Michael O. A. Ndanshau";
I am using explode function to get the names

$exp =explode(" ",$name);
print_r($exp);

 array output
Array
(
    [0] => Michael
    [1] => O.
    [2] => A.
    [3] => Ndanshau
)

from above array i can get the first name and last name
$fname = $exp[0];
$lname = end($exp);
```

am not sure how to get the middle name as it may be dynamic.

my target is to concatenate what is between the first element and the last as the **middle name**

```
if a have n elements in the array
$middename = $exp[1]+..$exp[n-1];
```

any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the first element of the array to get the first name and last element to get the last name. Get everything between for the middle name:

```
$firstname  = $parts[0];
$middlename = implode(array_slice($parts, 1, -1));
$lastname   = end($parts);

var_dump($firstname, $middlename, $lastname);
```

Output:

```
string(7) "Michael"
string(4) "O.A."
string(8) "Ndanshau"
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/134021)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this.  `array_shift` and `array_pop` modify the array so all that is left is the element(s) for the middle name:

```
$fname = array_shift($exp);
$lname = array_pop($exp);
middlename = implode(' ', $exp);
```

But you might want to check to make sure there are more than 2 elements up front, or at least 1 remaining:

```
$fname = array_shift($exp);
$lname = array_pop($exp);

if(count($exp) >= 1) {
    middlename = implode(' ', $exp);
}
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(count($arr)>2) {
    $middleName = implode(' ',array_slice($arr,1,count($arr)-2));
}
else {
   $middleName = '';
}
```